# Unable to capture screenshots using javascript in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to capture and save screenshots. However, the code mentioned below doesn't seems to work. I'm running iMacros addon on firefox.

```
var scrolling_isi_screenshot;

scrolling_isi_screenshot = "WAIT SECONDS = 5"+"\n";
scrolling_isi_screenshot += "SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=screenshot_{{number}}.png"+"\n";

for (var i=1; i<10; i++){
    iimSet("number",i)
    iimPlay(scrolling_isi_screenshot)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scrolling_isi_screenshot;

scrolling_isi_screenshot = "WAIT SECONDS = 5"+"\n";
scrolling_isi_screenshot += "SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=screenshot_{{number}}.png"+"\n";

for (var i=1; i<10; i++){
    iimSet("number",i)
    iimPlayCode(scrolling_isi_screenshot)
}
```

I just added one magic word :)

Comment: I had to diff to see it... `iimPlayCode` instead of `iimPlay`